# How to access list item using $index when using dirPaginate with Search filter applied

Tags: angularjs

I have list of objects.
I am displaying it using dirPaginate. I have added Search for one of the fields in the object. When we search, the index is starts from 0.
But I need to display the actual index of the list.

Comment: You should post your code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case you need to calculate manually like following example
if you are in second page and page sieze in 10 so following result is display

```
  <td> {{(pageIndex*pagesize)+$index}}<td> (if want to starting from 0)
  <td> {{(pageIndex*pagesize)+$index+1}}<td> (if want to starting from 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <td>{{ ($index + 1) + (currentPage - 1) * pageSize }}</td>
```